# How to properly filter Lists using object's ID and LocalDateTime fields in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, stream

Say we have following Dto Model.

```
public class OrderDto {
    Long id;
    LocalDateTime drawDate;
}
```

And we have following `List` which I need to filter and the result I need is also included.

```
List<OrderDto> orderDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(1L, LocalDateTime.now()));              // 1
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(1L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));  // 2
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(1L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2)));  // 3
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(2L, LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1))); // 4
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(2L, LocalDateTime.now()));              // 5
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(2L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));  // 6
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(2L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2)));  // 7
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(3L, LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(2))); // 8
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(3L, LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1))); // 9
orderDtoList.add(new OrderDto(3L, LocalDateTime.now()));              // 10

List<OrderDto> desiredList = new ArrayList<>();
desiredList.add(new OrderDto(1L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));   // 2
desiredList.add(new OrderDto(2L, LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));   // 6
desiredList.add(new OrderDto(3L, LocalDateTime.now()));               // 10
```

As you can see we have several `OrderDto` objects with the same ID, but I need to include in the desired list the ones which have `drawDate` more than `LocalDateTime.now()`. **BUT** only the first Object which is greater than `LocalDateTime.now()`. So obviously I need, the object with `plusDays(1)` not `plusDays(2)`. Desired List can't have Objects with same ID in it.

*ALSO Important thing*. If the objects with the **SAME ID** don't have `drawDate` greater than `LocalDatetime.now()`. Then I will need to choose object with the latest `drawDate`. ***AS SHOWN*** in the `desiredList`

Another thing. Desired List can't have Objects with same ID in it. And there might be even 10 `OrderDto` objects with the same id, but chosen one will be the first one whose `drawDate` is greater than `LocalDateTime.now()`

I'm trying to come up with Java STREAM that will do it for me but having trouble with it. ***Any other solution is welcome.***

Comment: what have you tried? What errors do you get?  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't start with a stream. Try doing it, and see if the solution you figure out could be refactored using a stream-based approach (and stay readable).

Comment: @P.J.Meisch , I have nothing to show off. Nothing to even close accomplishing my task.  I was trying out different stream combinations. Nothing significant.

Comment: I second JBNizet’s suggestion.  This seems fairly straightforward with a loop, but would be a royal pain using a Stream.

Comment: @VGR Well yea, it seems straightforward but still unable to do it with loops meh. Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've come up with a method that does the job for me. If anyone out there can think of something better feel free to post it. I used sorting because list might not be sorted by drawDates, so I just to make sure I sort them before I extract any elements from it. It assures I get the right one. Then I reverse list in order to get first object with the nearest date to `LocalDateTime.now()`.

```
 private List<OrderDto> getFilteredList(List<OrderDto> orderDtoList) {

    List<OrderDto> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    List<OrderDto> sortedList = orderDtoList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(OrderDto::getDrawDate)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (OrderDto dto : sortedList) {
        if (dto.getDrawDate().isAfter(now) && filteredList.stream().noneMatch(orderDto -> Objects.equals(orderDto.getId(), dto.getId()))) {
            filteredList.add(dto);
        }
    }

    Collections.reverse(sortedList);
    for (OrderDto dto : sortedList) {
        if (dto.getDrawDate().isBefore(now) && filteredList.stream().noneMatch(orderDto -> Objects.equals(orderDto.getId(), dto.getId()))) {
            filteredList.add(dto);
        }
    }

    return filteredList;
}
```